# How do I evaluate an expression with given arguments?

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, lisp, racket, evaluation

I'm currently trying make a function with following signature:

`(define (point-app F x))`

Which calculates F(x). My goal is to be able to evaluate the function F with x as argument.

So if I have:

`(point-app '(+(* x x) 4) 2)` <==> F(2) = (2^2)+4
the expected output would be 8.

I've tried using eval, by following drracket's [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/eval.html):

```
(define (point-fixe f x)
  (eval `(let ([number x]),f)))
```

But I cannot attach the variable x to number. As far as I know it's because eval dynamically loads the expressions? I've searched through common threads, but didn't find anything that would help me. Any aid would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: is it possible for you to write this as `(point-app (lambda (x) (+ (* x x) 4)) 2)`? Or must this be a quoted list? if the latter, and you have `(point-app '(list x y) 2)`, how do you know which of `'x` or `'y` to substitute with the given argument value, i.e. which one to use as a parameter placeholder, and which one to keep as a quoted datum? i.e. whether to return `'(2 y)` or `'(x 2)`?

Comment: It is assumed that first parameter would be F, and second x. The function I'm implementing is fixed point approximation which is F(x) = x ( there will be no variable y).I'm trying to avoid using lambda in the function call, since I want it to be more clean by adding ```'(expression)``` (more difficult expression --> more time to think of lambda func)

Comment: stick with the lambda, if you have any choice at all. otherwise you'll have to write your own evaluator. which is also fun, but unnecessary.

Comment: I've thinked about it, wouldn't it be nice to iterate through the expression, replace all ```x```'s with a number and then run eval on that new expression ?

Answer (score 1):

The way you express a function in lambda calculus is *λx.e* where *e* is some expression probably involving *x*.  This translates directly into Racket as `(λ (x) e)` where again *e* is some expression.

So your function simply needs to call its first argument, a function, on its second, some value:

```
(define (point-app F x)
  (F x))
```

If you want to express your functions as literal data (lists, say), then you can use `eval` to turn those into functions:

```
(define (source->function function-form)
  (eval function-form))
```

So now:

```
> (point-app (source->function '(λ (x) (+ (* x x) 4))) 2)
8
```

If you don't want to use the underlying mechanism of the language, then you need to write an evaluator.  That's not very hard and there are a lot of examples out there I am sure.